# Remap side buttons in Pulsefire Surge in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: mouse, configuration

I have this mouse, and I work in Ubuntu for development and programming, so I want to use the side buttons for running, debugging, etc. in my IDE's to make them more fast and comfortable. Is anything I can install? I saw a couple of posts here but they were for old Ubuntu versions (11). can someone help me? If they can change depending of the program I open, so, for example, the middle button means F5 in VSCode and means Crtl + Mayus + F10 in Pycharm, so I can run every program no matter what IDE I am using

Also, I would like to change dpi of the device, but it is not more important than the other problem, I can get used to the 1600 or 800 dpi from the default, but if I can change it, maybe it would be better.

Thanks everyone.